# How can I add "side-notes" to a text file in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I wonder how could I add the equivalent of side-notes (cues, thinking points indications, references) to a text in org mode?

Tags work fine, but they seem to be limited to headlines.

I could also divide the whole text in two fixed-size columns, (with a `|<140>|<20>|` table). However, in this last case, the text would not flow adequately.

Footnotes also are a way of adding extra information, but they won't be side-notes anymore. That's why they call them footnotes, I suppose.

What other options do I have? Could I for example open two buffers and somehow "tie" the scrolling of both so that line n of buffer a, always appears at the side of line n of buffer b?

Comment: Does the [`annotate`](https://github.com/bastibe/annotate.el) package (also available on Mepla) serve the purpose?

Comment: @kaushalmodi `annotate` didn't work quite well for me. So far, the best I found is the `scroll-all-mode`. I just open two parallel buffers. This has the drawback that both texts are not tied to each other though.

Comment: This is not what the original poster wants to hear, but I recommend just writing the notes underneath the heading, and forget about side-notes entirely.  Each note can begin with the standard `-`.  I like to use a dash followed by two spaces for each note underneath the main heading.  I have no blank lines between notes that relate to the heading directly above.  This way, there is no fiddling around with important stuff located somewhere else.

Comment: Here is the link to the manual regarding what I call notes, and which org-mode calls plain-lists:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-Lists.html#Plain-Lists

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is bookmark locations, and add annotations to the bookmarks.

If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then the bookmark [annotations](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkAnnotations) can themselves use Org Mode.  They can also be separate documents (which can even have their own bookmarks & annotations).

Answer (score 3):

You might find [comment lines](http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html) useful.  They will be set apart from the rest of the content and not exported.

> Lines starting with zero or more whitespace characters followed by one ‘#’ and a whitespace are treated as comments and, as such, are not
>   exported.
>
> Likewise, regions surrounded by ‘#+BEGIN_COMMENT’ ... ‘#+END_COMMENT’
>   are not exported.
>
> Finally, a ‘COMMENT’ keyword at the beginning of an entry, but after
>   any other keyword or priority cookie, comments out the entire subtree.
>   In this case, the subtree is not exported and no code block within it
>   is executed either1. The command below helps changing the comment
>   status of a headline.
>
> C-c ;
>       Toggle the ‘COMMENT’ keyword at the beginning of an entry.

Answer (score 1):

I like Drew's answer.  For the sake of completeness, I should mention [notes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html#Drawers).

If you want notes for each headline, but not be limited to one word tags, try writing timestamped notes stored in a property drawer next to the headline.  They can be anything in Org syntax.  You can conveniently enter them with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-z</kbd> on the headline.  You also have the option to export them by setting `org-export-with-drawers`.  However, if you want notes at any random point in the document, Drew's answer seems like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [inlinetasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345313)?

If you set `org-export-with-inlinetasks` to `nil` then they serve exclusively as side notes to the document author.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer? I jump through the link in your current answer but that requires me to jump to few other links to try to get a complete picture of what `org-inlinetask` is. It would be better if you can provide an example of how to use `org-inlinetask` and how it answers the OP's question. And then you can provide useful links to the original documentation instead of having the user jump via multiple links.